# JS: what's the promises equivalent of async.each?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async.js

Seems like it's been announced today that promises will be in ES6.

I've never been a promises guy - epic chains of .then() seem more complex than a simple list of functions in async.waterfall() but it looks like I'm going to have to learn them anyway.

So what's the equivalent of the other very popular workflow, [async.each()](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)?

```
async.each(items, processItem, function(err){
    doSomething(err)
});
```

Eg, run a processItem function over each item, once all have completed, continue with doSomething (doing something different if any of the processItem()s screwed up).

- How can I do this in promises?
- Is there an official place for promises user docs (not [the promises spec](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/), actual example workflows and how you'd do them in promises) like there for async?

Comment: Well, for starters, you are ignoring the kind-of-a-big-deal that if an exception happens in the waterfall, it will just crash the process. See http://jsfiddle.net/LvRs8/. You can use both try-catches and errbacks but you cannot possibly think that having 2 different styles of handling errors is simpler than promises where everything will propagate to `.catch()` like it would in synchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an official place for promises user docs (not the promises spec, actual example workflows and how you'd do them in promises) like there for async?

We have been putting together [a page of general promise resources](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources) on the Q wiki. In terms of workflows and composition, I believe ["How to Compose Node.js Promises with Q"](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-compose-node-js-promises-with-q/) would be the most helpful; it isn't really Node.js-specific, despite the title.

Comment: This is excellent - the [async to  promises gist linked inside it](https://gist.github.com/wavded/6116786) is particularly useful.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I do this in promises?

Assuming `processItem` does now not take a callback but returns a promise you would write

```
all(items.map(processItem)).then(doSomething);
```

Where `all` is your library's `all` function that takes an array of promises, like [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall). If you don't have one, this simple-minded implementation will do:

```
function all(promises) {
    return promises.reduce(function(m, p) {
        return m.then(function(res) {
            return r.then(function(r) { return res.concat([r]); });
        });
    }, fulfill([]));
}
```

> Is there an official place for promises user docs (not the promises spec, workflows and how you'd do them in promises) like there is async?

Nope. Every Promise library does have its own docs, and there are many tutorials on the web. "Official" are only the specs, which I think are short and understandable enough for the user to read though.